# C - Return statement not exiting void function

Tags: c, return

I am making a simple connect four game in C to reinforce what I have been learning in C. I've read in multiple places that a return statement in a void function should end execution of the function there. However, in the following code after putting a number into one array in row6, it also puts a number into row5 at the same column.

```
void putInBottomRow(int col, int player) {
if(row6[col] == 0) {
    row6[col] = player;
    return;
}
if(row5[col] == 0) {
    row5[col] = player;
    return;
}

return;
}
```

When I run this, this is the output:
[Command Window Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmVsM.png).
Am I missing something? Is the problem probably somewhere else in my code? Thanks.

Here is the other relevant code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int row1[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int row2[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int row3[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int row4[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int row5[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int row6[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

/*
  Use row six as bottom row and row 1 as top row.
*/

int main()
{
printf("\n   Connect Four\n");
printGameScreen();
printf("Player 1's turn.");
playerPlace(1);
printGameScreen();
printf("Player 2's turn.");
playerPlace(2);
printGameScreen();
return 0;
}

void playerPlace(int player) {
int rowChoice;
printf("Player 1's turn!\nWhich column (1-7)? ");
scanf(" %d", &rowChoice);
rowChoice--;
if(rowChoice > 6 || rowChoice < 0) {
    printf("That's not a row. Try again.");
    playerPlace(player);
    return;
 } else {
    switch(rowChoice) {
    case 0 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
    case 1 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
    case 2 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
    case 3 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
    case 4 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
    case 5 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
    case 6 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
    }

}
return;
}
```

Comment: Where are `row6` and `row5` defined? What are their values?

Comment: What happens when you use a step-through debugger?

Comment: [Please provide an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or the question will likely be closed.

Comment: Without seeing more code, there's not much we can do.

Comment: Are you sure you don't call that function twice instead of just once? That might very well be causing the behaviour you see.

Comment: probably you are forgetting that after the code after `case 5` executes, then the next statement is the next statement (i.e. calling `putInBottomRow` some more`, it does not jump to the end of the switch statement

Comment: `rowChoice` is supposed to be a row, but the argument of `putInBottomRow` is called `col`, and it's sometimes called a column ("Which column"), sometimes a row ("That's not a row"). Your indentation is bad. The switch is either buggy (you forgot all `break` statements, but if you put them it's useless since you do the same in each case), or if it's on purpose, it's equivalent to a loop. While there is a `player` argument to `playerPlace`, it always prints "Player 1's turn!".

Comment: Regarding the behaviour you noticed (two cells are modified), if you enter a number between 1 and 6, then rowChoice is between 0 and 5, then `putInBottomRow` is called at least two times (and exactly `7-rowChoice` times), because of the lack of `break` in the `switch`. Then, on the first call row6 is modified, and on the second call, since the cell in row6 is not zero in the first `if` in `putInBottomRow`, row5 is also modified. On later calls, neither of the `if` tests is true, and you exit the function with the third `return`, which is useless (a function always return at the end).

Comment: Your output is text. Please add it as text into your question. Images are for artwork or other graphical content.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
if (rowChoice > 6 || rowChoice < 0) {
    printf("That's not a row. Try again.");
    playerPlace(player);
    return;
} else {
    switch (rowChoice) {
    case 0 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
    case 1 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
    case 2 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
    case 3 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
    case 4 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
    case 5 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
    case 6 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
    }
}
```

As it stands, the function is executed 7 times if the row chosen is 0, 6 times for row 1, etc.  Superficially, you need a `break;` after each function call — execution flows through unless you add the break.  So at first glance you need:

```
if (rowChoice > 6 || rowChoice < 0) {
    printf("That's not a row. Try again.");
    playerPlace(player);
    return;
} else {
    switch (rowChoice) {
    case 0 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
        break;
    case 1 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
        break;
    case 2 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
        break;
    case 3 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
        break;
    case 4 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
        break;
    case 5 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
        break;
    case 6 :
        putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
        break;
    }
}
```

But further study shows that you're making the same function call regardless of the alternative.  You already detect and report out of range values (that's good), so the whole switch should become a single, simple function call, so you really only need:

```
if (rowChoice > 6 || rowChoice < 0) {
    printf("That's not a row. Try again.");
    playerPlace(player);
} else {
    putInBottomRow(rowChoice, player);
}
```

Note that the `return` in the `if` body is unnecessary; the statement after the `else` body is `return` too.  In fact, that `return` isn't necessary either since the function returns no value, so falling off the bottom of the function is no problem either.

You should check that the `scanf()` code is successful before using the `rowChoice`.  You should always check that inputs are successful.

Comment: That was it thank you! I know a switch is really overkill there but I'm just trying to make sure I can do everything because I just learned C. Good thing too because I didn't know how to do switch statements haha.